# Why is $\operatorname{Hom}(A, B)$ an abelian group?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, abelian-categories

Can someone please explain why a Hom-set (the set of all morphisms between two abelian groups $A$ and $B$) does also form an abelian group with addition? By the way both groups $A$ and $B$ have the same operation "$\cdot$".

Edit:  Yeah I've tried but: If $f$ and $g$ are morphisms between $(A,\cdot)$ and $(B,\cdot)$ then the result should still be a morphism from $(A,\cdot)$ to $(B,\cdot)$ right? (If the conclusion is true?) So the new $h=f+g$, which should be a morphism should respect $h(x\cdot y)=h(x)\cdot h(y)$ which adds up to:
$$f(xy)+g(xy)=f(x)g(x)+f(y)g(y)+f(x)g(y)+f(y)g(x)$$
which means that $f(y)g(x)+f(x)g(y)$ is $0$ and I can't explain that.

Comment: Hmmm....how urgent is this? And what have you tried? The definition of operation may be pretty problematic if these are *not* endomorphisms (from one group to **the same** group)...

Comment: @DonAntonio i've added an edit sry; these are still not endomorphisms since A and B are different sets, but with the same operation; yeah i've tried but : if f and g are morphisms between a,.) and (b,.) then the result should still be a morphism from a,.) to (b,.) right(if the conclusion is true) ? so the new h=f+g,which should be a morphism should respect h(x.y)=h(x).h(y) which adds up to: f(xy)+g(xy)=f(x)g(x)+f(y)g(y)+f(x)g(y)+f(y)g(x) which means that f(y)g(x)+f(x)g(y) is 0 and i cant explain that

Comment: @mateimanloache, in your calculation you use both $+$ and $\cdot$ for the operation in $B$. Stick to one notation for each group operation!

Comment: @mateimanloache, I added that calculation to my answer.

Comment: Another reminder: Just because the operations in $A$ and $B$ are both written "$\cdot$" doesn't mean it's the *same* operation. We just use the same symbol for two different operations and know which one to apply by looking at the elements. That's why I used different symbols for all operations in my answer.

Comment: @DonAntonio, they don't need to be endomorphisms; let the operations on $\mathrm{Hom}(X,Y)$ be induced by the operations of $Y$.

Answer (score 5):

First a bit of housekeeping.

Abelian groups are best viewed as possessing a notion of addition $+$, a notion of unary negation $-$, and notion of zero $0$. Thus, if $X$ and $Y$ are abelian groups, a good definition of "homomorphism" $X \rightarrow Y$ is that its a function $f : X \rightarrow Y$ satisfying the following identities.

1. $f(0_X) = 0_Y$
2. $f(-x) = -f(x)$
3. $f(x+x')=f(x)+f(x')$

You can then show from the axioms (which I will not list here, since they aren't very relevant, except insofar as they're all identities, and they entail the four very important identities listed below) that if $X$ and $Y$ are abelian groups and $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is a function, then condition 3 above suffices to conclude both 1 and 2. This simplifies what comes next; but isn't strictly necessary. I suggest that, for this particular problem, you pretend that all 3 identities above need to be demonstrated before we may conclude that $f$ is a homomorphism of Abelian groups, since you'll get a higher quality of insight.

Anyway, in this way we recover the usual definition of "homomorphism of Abelian groups," which from the viewpoint of [universal algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra) more like a *characterization* than an actual definition.

Now to answer your question.

The deeper reason that $\mathrm{Hom}(X,Y)$ forms an Abelian group is because the theory of Abelian groups is a [commutative algebraic theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/commutative+algebraic+theory). This is a concept that deserves to be better known.

Concretely, this means the following four identities are either axioms of Abelian group theory, or they're entailed by the axioms.

1. $-0 = 0$.
2. $0+0 = 0$.
3. $-(x+y) = (-x)+(-y)$.
4. $(x+y)+(x'+y')=(x+x')+(y+y')$.

For your interest, the fourth identity is called [mediality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_magma).

Anyway, the point is that using (just) these four observations, we can show the following:

> For all abelian groups $X$ and $Y$, the following sentences hold.
>
> 1. The unique function $0_{XY} : X \rightarrow Y$ that always returns $0_Y$ is a homomorphism.
> 2. Given a homomorphism $f : X \rightarrow Y$, the function $-f : X \rightarrow Y$ is a homomorphism.
> 3. Given a pair of homomorphisms $f,g : X \rightarrow Y,$ we have that $f+g$ is a homomorphism.

Thus $\mathrm{Hom}(X,Y)$ is *closed* under the operations induced by $Y$. Now the set of all functions $X \rightarrow Y$ is an abelian group under the operations induced by $Y$ (this is because abelian groups can be axiomatized by identities), and thus every subset of set of all functions $X \rightarrow Y$ that is closed under the induced operations is itself an abelian group (again, because abelian groups can be axiomatized by identities). In particular, we deduce that $\mathrm{Hom}(X,Y)$ is an abelian group with respect to these operations.

That's pretty much it; but feel free to comment if you have any questions.

---

By the way, if you're wondering where the 4 identities listed in the body of the answer come from, they come from a 3x3 grid of identities (3 because Abelian groups are equipped with three functions; a binary function +, a unary function -, and a nullary function 0). The aforementioned 3x3 grid gives rise 9 identities, listed below for your convenience. Removing the trivial ones and the redundancies, we obtain the 4 listed in the body of my answer.

```
1. 0 commutes with 0 : 0 = 0
2. 0 commutes with - : -0 = 0.
3. 0 commutes with + : 0+0 = 0.
4. - commutes with 0 : -0 = 0.
5. - commutes with - : --x = --x
6. - commutes with + : -(x+y) = (-x)+(-y).
7. + commutes with 0 : 0+0 = 0
8. + commutes with - : -(x+y)=(-x)+(-y)
9. + commutes with + : (x+y)+(x'+y')=(x+x')+(y+y').
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 4):

Let $(A,\cdot)$, $(B,\star)$ be abelian groups and
$$\operatorname{Hom}(A,B):= \{\ \varphi:A\to B \ |\ \text{$\varphi$ is a group homomorphism}\ \}.$$
Now you want to define an operation on $\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)$ to make it into a group. So for $\varphi,\psi:A\to B$ group homomorphisms, you are looking for some homomorphism $\varphi\bullet\psi:A\to B$. How should $\varphi\bullet\psi$ act on an element $g\in A$? We don't have much choice: Both $\varphi$ and $\psi$ give us elements $\varphi(g), \psi(g)\in B$, so we just multiply those in $B$ and take that:
$$ (\varphi\bullet\psi)(a) := \varphi(a)\star\psi(a) $$
for all $a\in A$.

Now you have to check that $\varphi\bullet\psi$ is a group homomorphism whenever $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are and that $(\operatorname{Hom}(A,B),\bullet)$ is an abelian group with the introduced operation. Both are easy tasks I'll leave to you.

**Edit**: Since you are struggeling with proving that $\varphi\bullet\psi$ is a homomorphism again: Let $\varphi, \psi: A\to B$ be homomorphism and $x,y\in A$:
\begin{align}
(\varphi\bullet\psi)(x\cdot y) &\stackrel{\text{def}}= \varphi(x\cdot y) \star \psi(x\cdot y) \stackrel{\text{$\varphi,\psi$ hom.}}= \left(\varphi(x)\star\varphi(y)\right)\star\left(\psi(x)\star\psi(y)\right) \\
&\stackrel{\text{$B$ abelian}}= \varphi(x)\star\psi(x)\star\varphi(y)\star\psi(y)
\stackrel{\text{def}}= (\varphi\bullet\psi)(x)\star(\varphi\bullet\psi)(y).
\end{align}

**Edit:** I changed the symbols of the operations, so see what is really happening.

Comment: i don't understand though,why are you working with ".", if the hom-set must form a group with addition , and not with ".". so shouldn't u proove that f+g)(x.y)=(f+g)(x).(f+g)(y) ?

Comment: I changed the symbols and chose to call the operation on the Hom-set "$\bullet$" now. Feel free to replace it with "$+$" if you like that better, after all: It's just a name for the operation. Usually you borrow the name from the operation in $B$, since you are just doing that pointwise.

Comment: + is just a name for an operation ? f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)...so you basically show there exists an operation with which hom(a,b) forms a group ?you have to show that for the operation + defined above I'm really thankful for your help it's just I'm new to this :)

Comment: What is $f(x)+g(x)$? $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are elements in $B$, all you can do is apply the group operation in $B$, which is "$\cdot$" in your example and now "$\star$" in my example. There is no such thing as $f(x)+g(x)$ if you don't have an operation called "$+$" in $B$.

Comment: ok ok thank you very much :D !

Answer (score 1):

Just check it.
Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a group and let $X$ be a set.
Then on the set $\operatorname{Map}(X,G)$ of maps $X\to A$ we can define a binary operation (again denoted with $\cdot$) by letting, for $f,g\colon X\to A$ $f\cdot g\colon X\to A$ be the map given by $(f\cdot g)(x)=f(x)\cdot g(x)$.

Then $(\operatorname{Map}(X,G),\cdot)$ is a group: Associativity is immediately inherited from $G$; the neutral element is the constant map to $1\in G$; the inverse of $f$ is the map tha maps to the inverse element-wise.

For any group $G$, we have that $\operatorname{End}(G)$ is a subset of $\operatorname{Map}(G,G)$, so we may wonder when this subset is in fact a subgroup. By the well-known subgroup criteria we need to check first of all that $f\cdot g$ is an endomorphism whenever $f,g$ are. That means that for $x,y\in G$ we must have $$(f\cdot g)(x\cdot y)=(f\cdot g)(x)\cdot(f\cdot g)(y),$$
i.e. 
$$f(x\cdot y)\cdot g(x\cdot y)=f(x)\cdot g(x)\cdot f(y)\cdot g(y). $$
As $f,g$ are endomorphisms, the left hand side equals $f(x)\cdot f(y)\cdot g(x)\cdot g(y)$ and the equation simplifies to $f(y)\cdot g(x)=g(x)\cdot f(y)$. This must hold especially for $f=g=\operatorname{id}_G$, i.e. we need $y\cdot x=x\cdot y$ for all $x,y\in G$ - the group $G$ must *necessarily* be abelian!
On the other hand, if $G$ is indeed abelian, then the above computations work out fine and $f\cdot g$ (or $f+g$ if we write the group operation additively for abelian groups) is indeed again an endomorphism of $G$. To complete the check of subgroup criteria, verify that the pointwise inverse of an endomorphism is again an endomorphism (because $G$ is abelian).

Comment: I guess you ment to say that ${\rm End}(G)$ is a subset of ${\rm Map}(G,G)$?

Answer (score 1):

There was a mistake in the book, so going through a different edition it appears as if the groups A and B have the same operation on them which is +, and u have to prove that (hom(A,B),+) is a group,which is pretty basic. so i don't think any of the answers are correct, because I get to an absurd point in trying to prove the problem stated above.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're saying, but if your book doesn't have a clean definition of the concept "Abelian group," I'd be happy to provide one. Also, note that just because two Abelian groups both have their operations denoted $+$, does not mean these are the same operations. Rather, the first operation is shorthand for $+_A$, while the second is shorthand for $+_B$

Comment: yes it does provide a clean definition of the concept. the + is addition. it is not a new operation you are defining, it is the clasical + in 1+1=2,and it is the same no matter what group you are working on. i might not know all of the story. i'm in the last year of high school and just started group theory so the sets in the groups i'm studying are basic sets (n,z,r,c,matrix sets,modular remainder sets,klein type groups ;basic stuff), so + works fine on these sets and doesn't need to be defined in any way;

Comment: and it also works in the same manner for all elements of the sets, so there is no +A and +B...again, i might not know all of the story, but i'm sure of the things i just said. thanks for the interest though, u're kind

Comment: Respect for getting started with abstract algebra in High school! Anyway, I think we can help. However, you'll have to edit your question with a word-for-word copy of the theorem as it is stated in your book. I think what the writer was *trying* to say, and what you're *interpreting* from the writing, are two very different things. If you can find the time to do this, you'll probably learn a lot from the answers.